# Projection onto $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Ax \leq b\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis

Consider the set $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Ax \leq b\}$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ real matrix, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and the inequality is meant componentwise.

Is there a closed form to express $P_C(x)$, $P_C$ being the orthogonal projection onto $C$?

If not in general, is there at least a closed form in the particular case where $C$ has the form
$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_i \in [l_i,u_i] \forall i, \sum_i x_i \in [l,u] \}$?

EDIT:
To be precise, $P_C(x) := \arg \inf_{c \in C}||x-c||$.

Comment: Something bothers me : you are speaking about the **orthogonal** projection onto $C$. But the shortest segment joining $x$ and $P_C(x) \in C$ will rarely be orthogonal to something. Don't you think that adjective "orthogonal" should be dropped ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I thought this was standard language. But very possible I was wrong. I edited the question and defined $P_C$.

Comment: @JeanMarie The "error vector" $x-c$ is what is orthogonal to the set $C$; the orthogonal projection is pretty standard language in minimum distance problems, like how the residual/error $\epsilon = y - \beta'X$ satisfies $\epsilon'X = 0$ in OLS. See p. 52, Luenberger, Optimization by Vector Space Methods, for example.

Comment: @Renard Thanks for your answer and reference. What I meant will be better understood if I take an example ; consider as "feasible set" the tetrahedron defined by $x>0,y>0,z>0,x+y+z<1$. and take $x=(2,0,0)$, we have $P_C(x)=(1,0,0)$ which is orthogonal to nothing in particular... Were the feasible set smooth, othogonality would mean something.

Comment: Take a look at this recent [PhD thesis](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jhaddock/Jamie/Dissertation.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

To see the difficulty with this request, notice that the set $C$ is defined by linear equalities, so that you could study the Lagrangian,
$$
\mathcal{L} = ||x-c|| + \sum_{k=1}^K \mu_k (A_k'x - b_k)
$$
which will have FONC's
$$
D_{x_j} ||x-c|| + \sum_{k=1}^K \mu_k A_{kj} = 0
$$
for $j=1,...,n$, and complementary slackness conditions $\mu_k (A_k'x-b_k) =0$ for all $k=1,...,K$. Since $||\cdot||$ is strictly convex and the constraint set is presumably convex if the problem is well-posed, the KKT conditions are sufficient. Strict convexity of the norm implies a unique solution. It will occur on the interior of a face of the convex polytope defined by $A$ and $b$, or at a vertex where one or more constraints intersect.

If you knew which constraint(s) was the binding one, I think you could just solve the FONC's by hand (min norm subject to one linear constraint). But because you don't know which $\mu_k$ are positive and which are zero, there won't be a simple closed form solution. You could solve for a closed form solution for each of the $K$ constraints, I guess, depending on what your particular question is, but different solutions will depend on the different coefficients of the hyperplane you are minimizing the distance to.

Comment: Thanks I see. But can you say something about the simpler case I mentioned?